# tr and row are not defined when trying to loop thru DataTable rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using JQuery 3.2.1 and DataTables 1.10.2

I have a DataTable that I populate from database using PHP:

```
<table id="tblActEcon" class="display nowrap table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Codigo</th>
      <th>Actividad Económica</th>
      <th>Seleccionar</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#tblActEcon').DataTable();

    $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
  });
</script>
```

The problem I have is that I get error `tr is not defined` and `row is not defined` when trying to loop thru DataTable rows like this:

```
$('#tblActEcon tr').each(function(row, tr){
    //do somenthing                 
});
```

Why is that?

Comment: try $('#tblActEcon tbody tr').each(function(row, tr){
    //do somenthing                 
});

Comment: It does not work

Comment: I just tried $('#tblActEcon tr').each(function(row, tr){
    //do somenthing   
    console.log(tr)
    
}); and it prints the tr https://jsfiddle.net/w8jxv2zt/19/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's working OK for me (even with datatables): https://jsfiddle.net/w92z6fka/2/

So you may have some other javascript issue giving you trouble.  Since you don't show where you are putting that `each` function, my guess is that you're doing it outside of the `document.ready`, in which case it will try to execute that before the `DataTable` initialization, but I'm not sure that matters.

In my example, I do the `each` inside the `document.ready` and then I grab the text contents of each  and append it to a log div, so that you can see the result.

You might also want to check for any javascript errors in your browser console...

Comment: Everything was fine as you said. the problem was that I was calling an **HTML class** instead of an **id** and the code did not get executed